# How do I get the value of the button clicked using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner and I wanted to start building projects and I want to determine the number of rounds using the value of the button the user clicks on.

```
    `<div class="game-type">
        <h2>GAME TYPE</h2>
        <p>choose the number of rounds you'd like to play</p>
        <div class="options">
            <button value="1" type="button">BEST OF 1</button>
            <button value="3" type="button">BEST OF 3</button>
            <button value="5" type="button">BEST OF 5</button>
            <button value="1000" type="button">FREE MODE</button>
        </div>
     </div>
```

`

using JavaScript I tried retrieving the value with "this" for the button that is clicked but it doesn't return anything at all. I want to use the value to set the RoundLimit value equal to the button pressed and end the game when RoundCount is equal to the round limit.

```
    `const rpsGame = () => {
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let roundCount = 0;
let roundLimit = 0;

// Universal value
const gameType = document.querySelector(".game-type");


//pick number of rounds to play
const roundNum = () => {
    const roundSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".game-type buttons");
    roundSelector.forEach(roundSelector => {
        roundSelector.addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log(this);
        });
    });
};
roundNum();`
```

Im a beginner any criticism is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Your code does not look correct. Are you trying to get user input via a button that is clicked?? You should use dropdown field that is read when the button is clicked and then read the dropdown field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's `button` instead of `buttons`

```
const roundNum = () => {
    const roundSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".game-type button");
    roundSelector.forEach(roundSelector => {
        roundSelector.addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log(this);
        });
    });
};
roundNum();
```

and to get the value

```
const roundNum = () => {
    const roundSelector = document.querySelectorAll(".game-type button");
    roundSelector.forEach(roundSelector => {
        roundSelector.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            console.log(e.target.value);
        });
    });
};
roundNum();
```